# Move HTML5 SVG path

Tags: jquery, html, svg, jquery-svg

I have a SVG path element in my application, like:

```
<path d="M100,100 Q200,400,300,100"/>
```

In a button click I have to move this path to the left, for example, from 100 to 200. I did it with the transform:

```
$('.path').each(function () {
    $(this).attr('transform', 'translate(100, 0)');
});
```

However, on the next click it does not move. How can I get the path element to move on each click?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

The translate will try to do exactly the same thing again. You need to store the value in a variable and use that:

```
var x=0;
$('.path').each(function () {
   x += 100;
   $(this).attr('transform', 'translate('+x+', 0)');
});
```

This example shows that you can move it 100 to right every click, so workout what you want to apply to x and you should be laughing.

Comment: Is there a non jquery answer?  ;(